# Settings windows too small in 3.6.5 after running project that was saved in 4.X

Tags: settings

4.0.1 was crashing constantly when animating so I wanted to go back to 3.6 but now the settings window that shows up when using any sort of functionality, like "triangulate faces" for example, is too small:

[image: window is small]

what it should look like:

[image: window not small]

I am in fact able to replicate this when running any other project in 3.6.4 that was saved in 4.X.
Is there any way to resolve this?
Ty.

---

edit: (I updated to 3.6.5 but the issue persists.)

Comment: Missing or problematic UI items aren't unusual when opening a file in an older major version than it was saved in. In the lower right corner there should be a warning message "File saved by newer Blender (4.0), expect loss of data." What happens if you hover your mouse over whatever that Triangulate Faces dropdown is called and then press F9? Even if that works for you as it did for me, there could be messed up UI in other workspaces. I have successfully copied and pasted objects from a new to an older version without problems. Continued...

Comment: ... I found this with an Internet search, it is talking about a different method and older versions of Blender, but maybe it will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195628/can-you-easily-export-a-blend-to-a-previous-version-of-blender

Comment: F9 works but who knows what other UI issues I may encounter if that's the case with running a newer file on an older version.

The warning message only shows for projects that were created in 4.X

link/append (from the method in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195628/can-you-easily-export-a-blend-to-a-previous-version-of-blender) only seems to let me add individual objects from the newer blend file one at a time, but not the whole scene, is there a way to do that?

Comment: I wish blender gave me a warning that I can't go back if saving an 3.6 project in 4.0.1.
I was running blender off steam so I wasn't aware of the update before it was too late.

Comment: Have you tried selecting all the objects in your scene and copy and pasting them into 3.6? Here is an ~6 minute YouTube tutorial that might help if you go the Append way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soWVMlBe_ww I just noticed when looking at the comments under that video that he has pinned one where the person uses copy/ paste. Here is something from the Blender Manual about compatibility that won't help with your problem, but might be of some interest: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/compatibility.html

Comment: The issue you are seeing has been asked about here at least 5 times recently for instance [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305807/how-to-resize-last-operation-window), so far without resolution. It appears to be a bug which should be reported via Help > Report a Bug in Blender. It doesn't necessarily seem to be due to changing Blender versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution I found is to use the [latest release of Blender 3.6.6](https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/) which fixes the issue.
And you need to save the project in question in 4.X again before saving it in 3.6.6 so that the new versioning code runs.
this could be suboptimal because using the latest release is likely unstable.

I wonder if I can then reinstall 3.6.5 to see if the project is now compatible after being saved in 3.6.6. I'll need to test that.

Edit: it does work so I'll mark this as the accepted answer unless there is another issue.