# Window when creating geometry is too small

Tags: modeling, vertices

Trying to create a circle. But the window tab that pops up once you click on one of the meshes inside 'create mesh', it became too tiny so I cannot change any vertices number for my circle. I hovered over the tiny window tab with my mouse by it doesn't show any sign that I can drag the corner to scale it up.

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: This has already been asked a number of times https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305994/settings-windows-too-small-in-3-6-5-after-running-project-that-was-saved-in-4-x